# How does the premium version of Here sdk api work?

Tags: android, android-studio, here-api

I signed up with Here sdk Api (Lite version) and I got a 'Freemium' account with an access_key_id and a secret_key as well. Now I want to upgrade my Freemium to Premium because I need the navigation tool for my application and they gave me an app code, api code and licence key (in the same account). when I built the application all I got is a blank page with a button and no errors in my terminal.

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.here_map_nav">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="XXX" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="XXX" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="XXX" />

    <service
        android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
        android:label="{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

By the way I don't know what to put in {YOUR_INTENT_NAME} and {YOUR_LABEL_NAME} . I don't know if it's the main problem or I should create an account for a premium version with my billing infos (since each account takes only one project)

Any help or clarifications would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below manifest.xml, it seems like action.VIEW is missing in yours.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" android:value="xx" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" android:value="xx" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```